# Caching python dictionary built from a list with increaing length

Tags: python, dictionary, caching

I want create a dict from a List like:

from:
`list_1 =  [['a', 'w'], ['b', 'x', 'k'], ['c', 'y'], ['d','z','h']]`

to:
`dict = {'a': 0, 'w': 0, 'b': 1, 'x': 1, 'k': 1, 'c': 2, 'y': 2, 'd': 3, 'z': 3, 'h': 3}`

with this code:

`dict = {item:i for i,subset in enumerate(list_1) for item in subset}  # code`

The question is that I add some data into list_1 everytime, for example **add 'r'** list_1[0].append('r') which makes:

`list_1 =  [['a', 'w', 'r'], ['b', 'x', 'k'], ['c', 'y'], ['d','z','h']]`

`dict = {'a': 0, 'w': 0, 'r': 0, 'b': 1, 'x': 1, 'k': 1, 'c': 2, 'y': 2, 'd': 3, 'z': 3, 'h': 3}`

When the dict list_1 get bigger, repeatly generating the dict cost too much calculation.
Anyone knows any method caching the dict, and making slightc modification to update the dict?
Many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

make a function to modify the dict when an item is added to a list

```
def add_to_list(location: int, value: str):
    list_1[location].append(value)
    old_num = dict.get(value)
    if not old_num:
         dict[value] = old_num
    elif (old_num < location):
         dict[value] = old_num
```

Comment: Thhanks! Seems reasonable. Delete the  comprehensions and use function to modify the dict.

Comment: @VolanHu I'm not sure what your use case is but you could use a dict/list comprehension to setup the initial dictionary and from there on out use the function. Depends how big your dictionary is as to if the additional code is worth while